# Bluetooth lowenergy TI CC2540 command to cancel connection request

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed c# application for TI CC2540 Bluetooth LE chip it works fine and perform all the task like btool. I have one difficulty is that, in my application there is a situation where I needs to connect to  keyfob without checking it is advertising or not. In that case if keyfob is not in advertising mode and if I  send command to connect it, it get stacked up in usb reader thats why it failed to connect to next keyfob connect command for other keyfob too...

So is there any method to empty all stacked command in usb reader or atleast any command to cancel connection request....(like DeviceDiscovery and scanDeviceDiscoveryCancel)

thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there should be , at the Bluetooth HCI level there is a HCI command to cancel a connection Request, So the tool you are using should also provide one, you should look at the documentation from the Vendor or ask them.